# Ajax call from rewritten url

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I'm trying to make an ajax call from within a page with a rewritten URL.

```
request = $.ajax({
                url: "myajaxcode.php",
                type: "post",
                data: formData
            });
```

The resulting request is `.../Folder/Rewritten_Name/myajaxcode.php`

For this to work the url should be `.../Folder/myajaxcode.php`

I also tried using a backslash in the url: "/myajaxcode.php", this resolves to 
    `/myajaxcode.php`

The ajax works when I provide the absolute URL or if I use a function that calculates and base URL and prefixes it the php file name. However, ideally I wanted to avoid using absolute urls or additional functions.

Is there a better way of handling the ajax call?

My htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^Rewritten_Name/([^/]+) Rewritten_Name.php?r=$1
```

Comment: That depends from within which HTML scope the ajax call gets run. The base url of the containing page is relevant. Yes, use absolute paths if you can't assert it reliably.

Comment: Thanks Mario. Yes, the issue was the HTML scope. In fact, at first the ajax call was returning the entire HTML page... till I realized that the issue was with the rewrite / ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a request from `example.com/Folder/foo.php` to `example.com/Folder/myajaxcode.php`
 you can use relative URl, like this:

```
request = $.ajax({
                url: "./myajaxcode.php",
                type: "post",
                data: formData
            });
```

Assuming that rewrite rules defined are correct, working exactly you want them to be & base url meta tag is set correctly in html.

further another approch, I have been people taking is: setting a global js variable from PHP in some function & the call the function in `<head>` where ever they want to  ajax. like this

```
<?php
 function set_ajax_url($script_path){
   $ajax =  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
   $ajax .= "window.MY_AJAX_URL = ";
   $ajax .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $script_path;
   $ajax .= "</script>";
   echo $ajax;
 }
```

add this in your template/layout

```
<html>
<head>
 <?php set_ajax_url('Folder/myajaxcode.php'); ?>
</head>
```

you use can this like this:

```
request = $.ajax({
                url: MY_AJAX_URL,
                type: "post",
                data: formData
            });
```

so, you will have to change the url at one place :)

Comment: He is saying he don't want to use absolute URLs, but I agree with setting an absolute path by PHP because that's what I do my self.

Comment: Thanks Gaurish, Mahan. Yes, I tried absolute path and the common function / base_url but wondered if there's a better way.